# Unable to create file in C:\TEMP

Tags: java

Following on from a previous question, for some reason when I use the following code :

```
    final File tmpDir = new File("C:/TEMP/", zipFile.getName());

    if(!tmpDir.mkdir() && tmpDir.exists()) {
        System.err.println("Cannot create: " + tmpDir);
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

I get an error (Cannot create: C:\TEMP\aZipFile) however, if I use the following:

```
    final File tmpDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), zipFile.getName());

    if(!tmpDir.mkdir() && tmpDir.exists()) {
        System.err.println("Cannot create: " + tmpDir);
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

it works perfectly. My problem is that I want to use C:\TEMP as this is consistent with the rest of the project I am working on.

Again, I'm using Java 1.4 on Windows XP and JDeveloper IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(!tmpDir.mkdir() && tmpDir.exists())
```

Shouldn't this be:

```
if(!tmpDir.mkdir() && !tmpDir.exists())
```

Comment: Yes, first part of the sentence tries to create the temp dir, returning true if it creates or false if it can't create or already exists, this posibility is covered by the second part of the if. So that the if is true only if the temp dir doesn't exist and it can't be created

Answer (score 1):

Well, if `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")` does not return 'C:\TEMP' it's not the same. While I'd suggest to rely on java.io.tmpdir, you could also make sure that C:\TEMP exists - or create it if needed: ``;

```
File temp = new File("C:/TEMP/");
if (!temp.exists()) temp.mkdir();
File tmpDir = new File(temp, zipFile.getName());
```

Alternatively, you could change your code to

```
final File tmpDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), zipFile.getName());

// note the change from mkdir to mkdirs
if(!tmpDir.mkdirs() && !tmpDir.exists()) {
    System.err.println("Cannot create: " + tmpDir);
    System.exit(0);
}
```

EDIT: I've just seen the answer by atomice and he's right: it's `!tmpDir.exists()` rather than `tmpDir.exists()`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use `File.createTempFile`, isn't it what you trying to archive?

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you don't have write access to `"C:/TEMP/"`  or that TEMP folder doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

Did you compare the result of 'System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")' with what you are trying?
Also, on WindowsXP I'd go for "C:\Temp\" as the directory name.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a file in the temp dir with the name you want that is locked?